# Create helpers function for displaying validation errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, validationerror

To display validation errors after input field I using:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Html::decode(Form::label('first_name','First Name:<span class="required">*</span>',['class'=>'control-label col-sm-3'])) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        {!! Form::text('first_name',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        @if ($errors->has('first_name'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Html::decode(Form::label('last_name','Last Name:<span class="required">*</span>',['class'=>'control-label col-sm-3'])) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        {!! Form::text('last_name',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        @if ($errors->has('last_name'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('last_name') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
// and so on......
```

This code works perfectly. But I have to write almost same code in every single input box. So, I planned to make a global function to display errors. To achieve this I did the following.

1. Create a `helpers.php` inside `app` folder
2. Write the following code:

   ```
   function isError($name){
       if($errors->has($name)){
           return '<span class="help-block"><strong>'.$errors->first($name).'</strong></span>';
       }
   }
   ```
3. run `composer dump-autoload`
4. Used it in blade file this way:

   ```
   <div class="form-group">
       {!! Html::decode(Form::label('first_name','First Name:<span class="required">*</span>',['class'=>'control-label col-sm-3'])) !!}
       <div class="col-sm-6">
           {!! Form::text('first_name',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
           {{ isError('first_name') }}
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       {!! Html::decode(Form::label('last_name','Last Name:<span class="required">*</span>',['class'=>'control-label col-sm-3'])) !!}
       <div class="col-sm-6">
           {!! Form::text('last_name',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
           {{ isError('last_name') }}
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Now, when I go to `create.blade.php` I have an error

> Undefined variable: errors (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\hms\resources\views\guest\create.blade.php)

I know the problem is in `helpers.php` because I didn't defined the `$errors`, I just paste that code from blade file.

Comment: `$errors` isn't defined in your helper. You need to pass the errors object to the `isError()` function. For example `isError($errors, last_name')`.

Comment: @Jeemusu Nice idea. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Jeemusu Yeah, it worked. additionally I changed in blade `{!! isError($errors,'first_name') !!}` to escape the html tag. Can you make it an answer, so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `$errors` variable is undefined within the scope of your helper method.

This can be easily solved by passing the `$errors` object to the `isError()` helper method.

## Helper

```
function isError($errors, $name){
    if($errors->has($name)){
        return '<span class="help-block"><strong>'.$errors->first($name).'</strong></span>';
    }
}
```

## Blade Template

```
{!! isError($errors, 'first_name') !!}
```